# Keras LSTM to Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I am using the following code to apply sequential LSTM to time-series data with one value. It works fine with a Keras version. I am wondering how could I do the same using PyTorch?

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras import losses
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Dropout, Embedding, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop, Adam, Nadam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import sequence
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

# training_dataset.shape = (303, 24, 1)
time_steps = 24
metric = 'mean_absolute_error'
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=32, activation='tanh', input_shape=(time_steps, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=[metric])
print(model.summary())

batch_size=32
epochs=20

model.fit(x=training_dataset, y=training_dataset,
                       batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs,
                       verbose=1, validation_data=(training_dataset, training_dataset),
                       callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='../logs/{0}'.format(tensorlog))])

testing_pred = model.predict(x=testing_dataset)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the pytorch documentation for that: https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html

the simplest code is the following:

```
   import torch, torch.nn as nn, torch.optim.Adam as Adam

   model = nn.Sequential(nn.LSTM(input_size=1, hidden_size=32, output_size=1), nn.Sigmoid)
   opt = Adam(model.parameters())
   loss_func = nn.MSELoss()

   for (x, y) in dataloader:
      opt.zero_grad()
      pred = model(x)
      loss = loss_func(y, pred)
      loss.backward()
      opt.step()
```